# Node JS, Mongoose How to query schema via aggregate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to using MongoDB and I am trying to update update my document using aggregate $set pipeline. However I have been trying this for a few days and there is still no success. I am trying to update by querying `ObjectId` and replacing matched result (singular) with the key value pair I specified. I tested the aggregate on Mongo Compass and it works. Does anyone know how to use aggregate for Node JS?

updateOne query I tried

```
let query = {"_id": ObjectId('theObjectIamUpdating')};
response = await newForm.updateOne(query, payload);
```

aggregate query I tried

```
response = await newForm.updateOne([
      {$match: {"_id": ObjectId(update_id)}},
      {$set: {
        "data.velo": [
            [1, 2, 3], [5, 7]
          ]
      }}
    ]);
```

newForm Mongoose Schema

```
data: {
        date: {
            type: Array,
            required: false,
            trim: true,
        },
        speed: {
            type: Array,
            required: false,
            trim: true,
        },
        velo: {
            type: Array,
            required: false,
            trim: true,
        }
    },
calc: {
        date: {
            type: Array,
            required: false,
            trim: true,
        },
        speed: {
            type: Array,
            required: false,
            trim: true,
        },
        velo: {
            type: Array,
            required: false,
            trim: true,
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**
I my updateOne() has succeeded, but my documents are not getting updated.

the result I got after logging response that I awaited

```
Data received  {
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 0
}
POST /api/compute/calculate 200 16 - 79.821 ms
```

Additionally, this is the MongoDB aggregate that worked when I tried on Mongo Compass

```
pipeline = $match > $set

**$match**
{
  "_id": ObjectId('62e2295060280132dbcee4ae')
}
**$set**
{
  "data.velo": [
      [1, 2, 3], [5, 7]
    ]
}
```

where `velo` is one of the key value pairs in data, and the set result replaced only the data in `data.velo`.

Comment: Are you sure about the `updateOne` Mongoose syntax?

Comment: I read through the mongoose document and it takes 4 params (query, data, options, callback). This was also another example I saw on [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongoose-updateone-function/).

Comment: Do let me know if I am using the wrong syntax/method. [Official Document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/).

Comment: On a successful update `modifiedCount: 0`, this value will be `1` (and the `matchedCount` will be `1`).

Comment: I see, which means that my query is not finding the matching `ObjectId`

Comment: @prasad_ Thank you for your help, I have realised that although my updateOne() was correct, I was created a newModel my doing new on my already existing model. It was quite a silly mistake. Thank you for your time. I will leave this open for now because I have yet to update all my key value pairs just in case I run into more problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As prasad_ mentioned in the comment section, I indeed found some mistakes with regards to my syntax of `updateOne()`.

Correct Syntax for updateOne()

```
let response = await Form_csv_metadata2.updateOne({ '_id': [update_id] }, [
      {//delete this line $match: {"_id": ObjectId(update_id)},
        $set: {
        "data.velo": [[1, 2, 3], [5, 7]]
      }}
    ]);
```

As the official document has mentioned the parameters are: Query, UpdateData and Option. I made the mistake as my query was placed in my `UpdateData()` param (the `$match`). It should have been a param by itself as a query (query uses same syntax as `find()`). Another note is that if I were to use a pipeline aggregate, it should have been `{ $match: {...}, $set: {...} }` instead of `{ {$match: {...}}, {$set: {...}} }`